# how to give different names to different checkboxes when checkboxes are created from while loop

Tags: html, jsp

I am creating checkboxes at runtime, in a while loop according to an amount of data coming from a database.
Now I want to know what I should write in the attribute name to give a different name to each checkbox. Also for the value, if I want to pass the value of rs.getString(1) using jsp.
Here is a piece of my code.

```
<%while(rs.next())
{
%><tr><td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="" value="">
<%
for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
%>
<td align="center">
<%=rs.getString(i)%>
</td>
<%}%>
</tr>
<%}%>
```

Comment: You could use a counter. Increment it by one in every iteration.

Comment: i have tried it but i cant give a variable in attribute

Comment: But you already have `<%=rs.getString(i)%>`. That is very similar to how you could set `name` and `value`.

Comment: sir <%=rs.getString(i)%> this is used for print the value. but when im useing it inside the atribute its generating a jsp error

Comment: i have to give name attribute at run time :(